# Send image over socket and almost all bytes replaced with "?"

Tags: c#, c++, image, sockets, bitmap

I want to send picture via socket but when I get the picture in the second side the bytes not the same.
server(CPP), client(C#).

CPP:

```
        std::ifstream fin("1.bmp", std::ios::binary);
        std::string data;
        data.reserve(1000000);
        std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
            std::back_inserter(data));
        fin.close();
        send(clientSocket, data.c_str(), data.size(), 0);
```

C#:

```
 s = new SocketHandler(ip, Int32.Parse(port));
            bits = unicode.GetBytes(s.recive());
            File.WriteAllBytes("newff.bmp", byts);
```

Comment: Why are you doing `unicode.GetBytes(s.recive());` ? Why are you using Unicode encoding **at all**?

Comment: In C#/.NET, a `char` value is a 16-bit UTF-16 code-point, **not** an 8-bit `byte` (C#/.NET has a `byte` type for that purpose). A C `char` maps to a C# `byte`.

Comment: `SocketHandler` is not a type in .NET. What is your `SocketHandler` class, exactly?

Comment: Yes SocketHandler  its my class.

Comment: Please post the definition of your `recive()` method. Why aren't you using the original Sockets API instead?